# typescript: ddd + delivery message

Tags: typescript, rabbitmq, domain-driven-design

Hello I have the following question regarding ddd and rabbitmq:

I have two microservices:

employee and departments

and to create a department I need to get the employee id from the employee microservice.

But I have the following question: do I have to get my employee from the cache in my department's domain or do it in my service?

I have a cache that I keep only the id and name of the employee in my department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are looking for a specific solution, but there are many core problems with the question you are asking:

Microservices should not be built around data structures. It seems like **Employee** and **Department** are two tables in your system, and you are trying to develop Microservices around them. But that is wrong and will lead to increased complexity. The question you are asking is an excellent example of the complexity - increased sharing of data between the two microservices. Your microservices should enclose "areas", "workflows", or "functions" of your domain.

Three simple rules that give you the answer to your specific question:

- **Microservices share nothing**: All data, behavior, technology is enclosed within the Microservice. The external world should not be able to access data except through well-defined APIs. These APIs could be REST-based, message-based, RPC-based, or anything else, except for direct access to the tables.
- **Microservices own their master data and everybody else caches it**: It's not a good idea to call Microservice APIs synchronously. It is better to cache data locally within your Microservice if needed. There are message-based, reactive architectures that allow you to do this in realtime, but you should account for the increase in complexity in workflow and debugging.
- **Microservices can share data with the help of Domain Events**: While you can set up the caching mechanism synchronously, it is recommended that you propagate state with Domain Events.

You should review the "Strategic Design" part of DDD more deeply, to be able to construct useful, maintainable microservices. Unless you get the boundaries right, you are setting up yourself for increasing complexity.

Comment: so I already use the cache with redis, when starting the server I get the data of my employees by amqp protocol, my doubt is where I would put this example code: if there is no employee id in my cache, send by amqp protocol for om i employee check if there is this employee in the base.

Comment: I'm doing it at the learning level, I understand that it's more complex, but I'm trying to unravel

Comment: IMHO, it would be easier and much safer to listen to Domain Events published by the Employee Microservice, fetch the employee data to the cache when an event is received, and use the cache data later. This will prevent the need for the Department's service to talk to Employee service in synchronous mode.

Comment: do you speak at the domain event that creates an employee send a message to my department microservice?

is this and mock on cache?

but wouldn't it be nice to also have a team to renew the cache data with a getAll on my employee microservice?